# django-tables2: fetch cell value

Tags: django-tables2

I render a table with django-tables2.This is it:

```
class VehiclesTable(tables.Table):
    id = tables.TemplateColumn(verbose_name=' ',template_name='editButton.html')
    plate = tables.Column(verbose_name='plate')
    vht_id = tables.Column(verbose_name='vht_i')
    vlength = tables.Column(verbose_name='vlength')
    vwidth = tables.Column(verbose_name='vwidth')

    class Meta:
       attrs = {'class': 'custom'}
```

I have a template column(id) that each cell of it has a button that each one renders a template. In the view that handles this template I want to pass  the value of the cell next to the button cell (same row->plate). This value will be used to query the object that I want to render in a form on the new template with the button click. How can i fetch the value of the  next django table cell(plate) when the user "hits" the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TemplateColumn` renders the template using a context containing a `record` variable (as described in the [documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#templatecolumn-objects)).

In your case, this means in `editButton.html` you can access the `plate` value via `{{ record.plate }}`.

Comment: pure awesomeness, that's why I love django-tables2! Thank you

Comment: sth maybe trivial: how can I change the position of the table if I use the paleblue theme?where in screen.css? maybe by adding .paleblue{..}?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Could you make a new question and ask your question in a more generic way, and I'll answer it there.